# In Intellij Idea beans.xml are not being created in target directory

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I've started working on a spring project, and I'm using Intellij IDEA. I've found that when I run the app it actually compiling the classes to the **target/classes** directory and running from it.

But, when I've added a beans.xml in the same location of my main class and write necessary codes with **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** that beans.xml is not getting placed in the **target** directories designated location so that many errors are rising.

But when I'm placing the beans.xml in the target directory it's working fine.

What am I doing wrong here? In what structure should beans.xml files be created so that It automatically syncs to target directory?

Comment: You should place it in `resources` directory instead of the sources directory.

Comment: Okay, So if I've placed it in resources, and called it with FileSystemXmlApplicationContext, that ran fine. But, when do I use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext?

Comment: Please check Maven/Gradle docs for the standard locations of the resources. Only resources from these locations will be copied to the classpath. Resources present in the source roots are not copied to the classpath by default and would require additional configuration in your build files.

Answer (score 0):

First I was putting xml file in the src/main/java directory while following a youtube tutorial but he was doing it in eclipse and and it was not working for me in IntelliJ-Idea

If you put xml file directly in the target file, it works because after compilation, result are copied over there.

But for standard procedure you should create an another directory named "resources" in the "src/main/" (final path: "src/main/resrouces" and then create xml file in the directory as soon as you run this project you can see this file also automatically get copied in the target direcoty.

[image]